Efficiently applying a rotation from a unit quaternion to a general quaternion
Is there a way to more efficiently compute the resulting quaternion $r · q · r^{-1}$ where $r$ is assumed to be a unit quaternion (so $r^{-1}$ can be assumed to be the conjugate of $r$), and $q$ is a general quaternion, than simply by doing two separate general quaternion multiplications, each of which uses 16 multiplications and 12 additions?

Hi! What's the context here? Are you coding something up?

Yes, my gut suggests there should be a faster way then just general quaternion multiplication, but I'm not sure what it is.

Yes. I'm going to swap letters and say that we care about the map
$$
H: x \to q^{-1} x q
$$
where $q$ is a unit quaternion. Observation 1: if $x$ is a pure-real quaternion, i.e.
$$
x = a + 0i + 0j + 0k
$$
then it's invariant under $H$, i.e. $H(x) = x$.
Also, $H$ is linear (I leave this to you to prove).
In fact, $H$ is a product of two orthogonal maps (left-multiplication my $q^{-1}$, right-multiplication by $q$), so $H$ also maps the orthogonal complement of pure-real quaternions -- the "pure vector quaternions" -- to itself. Writing
$$
x = bi + cj + dk
$$
as a vector
$$
x' = \pmatrix{b\\c\\d}
$$
we can then find a matrix $R$ with the property that
$$
H(x') = Rx'.
$$
The good news is that we don't have to. Rodrigues' Formula does it for us. So just go read up on that, and you'll be in good shape. Instead of two 4x4 multiplies, you'll be doing one 3 x 3 multiply.
(I personally recommend the description in Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice by Hughes et al., but I'm biased.)
A bit of trivia: the formula is named for Olinde Rodrigues, which I've always liked because I think "Olinde" is a great name, and one I've never seen elsewhere.
Post-comment additions
Let's give the pure-vector quaternions a name, $V$, and call the pure-real quaternions $W$. Let's call the set of all quaternions $X$. There are two projection maps:
$$
\pi_V: X \to V : a + bi + cj + dk \to bi + cj + dk \\
\pi_W : X \to W : a + bi + cj + dk \to a + 0i + 0j + 0k.
$$
Then there are isomorphisms
$$
\alpha_V: V \to \mathbb R^3 : bi + cj + dk \to \pmatrix{ b\\c\\d} \\
\alpha_W: W \to \mathbb R: a + 0i + 0j + 0k \to a .
$$
So far so good? Let's just compute
$$
\alpha_V(\pi_V ( 3 + 2i + 6j - 2k)) = 
\alpha_V(2i + 6j - 2k) = \pmatrix{2 \\6\\-2}.
$$
I'll bet that you can compute $\alpha_W (\pi_W(3 + 2i + 6j - 2k))$ as well. If you're not sure, try it and tell me in the comments what you get.
OK. Now let's suppose that we have the Rodrigues matrix $R$ for our unit quaternion $q$. It's a 3x3 matrix.
To compute $H(s)$, we're going to do several steps:

Write $s = a + (bi + cj + dk)$.
Observe that this means $H(s) = H(a+ 0j + 0j + 0k) + H(0 + bi + cj + dk)$, because $H$ is linear.
Compute the first term, $H(a+ 0j + 0j + 0k) = a+ 0j + 0j + 0k$ because $a+ 0j + 0j + 0k$ is a pure-real quaternion, on which $H$ acts as the identity.
Compute the second term, $H(0 + bi + cj + dk)$, like this:
a. Apply $\alpha_V$ to the argument to get the 3-vector $\pmatrix{b\\c\\d}$.
b. Multiply this by the matrix $R$ to get some vector $\pmatrix{r\\s\\t}$.
c. Apply $\alpha_v^{-1}$ to this to get $0 + ri + sj + tk$.
Add this to the result of step 3 to get $a + ri + sj + tk$.

Let's make this wicked explicit by supposing that $R$ is the matrix
$$
R = \pmatrix{3 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\\ 2 &1 & 1}
$$
That's total nonsense, of course, but it gives me digits to work with, and no decimal values, so it's easier to show the whole process. Once again, I'll start with the quaternion
$$
g = 3 + 2i + 6j - 2k.
$$
For the "3" part, we have $H(3 + 0i +  0j + 0k) = 3$. Hold that thought.
For the pure-vector part, we convert $2i + 6j - 2k$ into the vector $\pmatrix{2\\ 6 \\-2}$, and multiply it by $R$ to get
\begin{align}
z 
&= R \pmatrix{2 \\6\\-2}\\
&= \pmatrix{3 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\\ 2 &1 & 1} \pmatrix{2 \\6\\-2} \\
&= \pmatrix{2 \\8\\8} \\
\end{align}
and then we apply $\alpha_V^{-1}$ to convert this to $0 + 2i + 8j + 8k$.
We combine this with the real part to get our new quaternion
$$
3 + 2i + 8j + 8k
$$
and we're done.
Now I don't know how you're representing quaternions. There's a pretty good case for using an array of four floats to do so. Let's say that the quaternion $q = a + bi + cj + dk$ is fixed, and we want to apply it to some quaternion represented by four floats -- the coefficients of $1, i, j, k$, in that order in an array $x$, so that x[0] is the real part, and x[1:3] is the pure-vector part. In rough pseudocode:
precomputation: 
float R[3][3] = [a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2, 2(bc - ad), 2(bd + ac),
                 2(bc + ad), a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - d^2, 2(cd - ab),
                 2(bd - ac) 2(cd + ab), a^2 + d^2 - b^2 - c^2];

// computation done to rotate a particular quaternion x
float[3] rotate(float x[4]){
   float u[4] 
   u[1:3] = R * x[1:3]; // I'm assuming your language has matrix mult'n as a built-in.
   u[0] = x[0];
   return u; 

Total work: 9 multiplies, 6 adds, and one "copy", as well as some indexing.

that's for taking a vector x and finding the vector x'.   What if x is not a vector, but another quaternion?

See post-comment addition.

In pseudocode
Quaternion rq;
Vector3d v = r.vec.cross(q.vec) + r.w * q.vec; //9mul
Vector3d u = r.vec.cross(v); //6mul
rq.vec = q.vec + u + u;
rq.w = q.w;

15 multiplications. Faster than 2 direct multiplications.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It literary answer the question.
